# How can I show album art in an iOS 7 app when using AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: ios

I have an app where I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer to read a document to a user. I allow the user to control the speech playback using the remote control events from the lock screen:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

There are images associated with the document, and I would like to show an image on the lock screen just like how music apps show album art when a song is playing. Does anyone know how I could provide a URL or image location and have that image get displayed on the lock screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This sets the Now Playing information for an app that is playing media and displays it on the lock screen.